# ImageView is zooming in on table row deletion Part II

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have the exact same problem as the question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22886721/imageview-is-zooming-in-on-table-row-deletion/27389774#27389774).

Which looks exactly like this [gif](http://gfycat.com/FeistyIckyAsiaticgreaterfreshwaterclam).

I'm not which method to begin troubleshooting the problem.  I've sub-classed the UICell and have used the standard UICell, both with the same results.  I've also tried to set the image in the cell to nil when it edit mode:     `cell.imageView.image = nil;`

Any thoughts would be appreciated, I can post more code if needed...

// Cell For Row At Index Path

```
(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSLog(@"Item cell func");

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"detailCell";

    MCTableViewCell *cell = nil;
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[MCTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }

    // Configure the cell...

    Item * record = [_itemsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:record.photo];

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@", record.itemName];
    cell.textLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;

    //cell.shouldIndentWhileEditing = NO;

    NSLog(@"Detail Record.Name %@", [_itemsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);

    return cell;
}
```

// Editing Cells

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{




    NSLog(@"Begin editStyle Func");

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        //UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone

        //    1
        [tableView beginUpdates];
        // Delete the row from the data source

        NSLog(@"after Updates editStyle Func");

        // Delete item from Table
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

        NSLog(@"after Row Animation editStyle Func");



        // Delete Item from Database
        [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:[self.itemsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];


        NSError *error;
        if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }

        [self showObjects];

        NSLog(@"End of if stmnt");

        //    5
        [tableView endUpdates];

    }


    NSLog(@"End of Function");
}
```

Comment: Have you tried overriding `willTransitionToState` or `didTransitionToState` in your custom cell, if only to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem seems to happen in ios7.
in ios8, works fine. so, this might be a bug.

To work around, add your own UIImageView to cell and use it instead of UITableVewCell's imageView.

Comment: Thanks, I had tried sub-classing the cell previously with the same results.  The missing piece was found in this solution: [Perform With Out Animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19711958/unwanted-image-animation-when-resizing-uitableview/21740761#21740761)  Can you add your own image to a UITableViewCell without sub-classing?

Comment: yes. using UITableView's Dynamic Prototypes in storyboard is easy way. [(see this document)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW20) if you don't use storyboard, you will have to create custom cell.[(Custom cell with nib)](http://mrmaksimize.com/ios/Custom-UITableViewCell-With-NIB/)